# Rails ActiveRecord association "has_many, each of which has_one"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a question regarding ActiveRecord associations, where I'm trying to have a `User` model, where each user can have many `Product`s (which then belong to that specific user). However, before the product is on display, it needs an active permission, so I want to add a third model, `Permission`, to said construct.

I formulated following sentence to make the thinking process easier:
One `User` has_many `Product`s, each of which has_one `Permission`.

The ActiveRecord associations look like this right now:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :permissions
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :permission
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My questions:

1. is this the correct approach (does it actually work?)
2. is it necessary to declare that `User` has_many permissions and `Permission` belongs_to user if I never need to list all permissions of a user in my app?

I want to ask you guys for confirmation if my thoughts are correct or if it's wrong or if there is a better way to master my problem and I hope the question is also useful to others, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer both questions at the same time. The code will work (given the correct migrations), but not for what you want. Remove the `has_many :permissions` from the User class and `belongs_to :user` from the Permission class.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's ok.
2. It should be `has_many :permissions, through: :products`, if you want it is able to get `permissions` from a user, but in `permissions` table does not contain `user_id` column.

The db query is generated like:

```
SELECT "permissions".* 
FROM "permissions" INNER JOIN "products" ON "permissions"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
WHERE "products"."user_id" = [user_id]
```